# Support for Any field in Protobuf.js

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf.js

I am using `Protobuf.js` for Node and it seems that the [`Any`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any) field type from proto3 is [not supported yet](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/issues/435).

The author of the module suggest to manually define `Any` just like below.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package google.protobuf;
message Any {
  string type_url = 1;
  bytes value = 2;
}
```

However, it's not very clear to me what's I should do after that. I have written a minimal script which successfully uses the workaround:

**myservice.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";  

package myservice;

message Any {
  string type_url = 1;
  bytes value = 2;
}

message Request {
    string id = 1;
}

message SampleA {
    string fieldA = 1;
}

message SampleB {
    string fieldB = 1;
}

message Response {
    string id = 1;
    repeated Any samples = 2;
}

service MyService {
  rpc Get (Request) returns (Response);
}
```

**samples.js**

```
const ProtoBuf = require('protobufjs');
const builder = ProtoBuf.loadProtoFile('./myservice.proto');
const Any = builder.build('Any');
const SampleA = builder.build('SampleA');
const SampleB = builder.build('SampleB');
const Response = builder.build('Response');

const pack = (message, prefix) => {
  return new Any({
    type_url: path.join((prefix || ''), message.toString()),
    value: message.encode()
  });
};

const unpack = (message) => {
  const b = builder.build(message.type_url.split('.')[1]);
  return b.decode(message.value);
};

// Pack and create a response
const sampleA = new SampleA({fieldA: 'testa'});
const sampleB = new SampleA({fieldA: 'testa'});
const response = new Response({
  id: '1234',
  samples: [pack(sampleA), pack(sampleB)]
});


// Unpack
const samples = response.samples.map((sample) => {
    return unpack(sample);
});
```

This works and I get back what I expected. However, I have a couple of questions:

1. Is there a better way to get the full name of a message to construct the type_url. I used .toString() in my code but I had a look at the implementations of other languages and messages seem to have some kind of getter for the name.
2. When encoding and decoding an Any message should I use .encode and .decode or is there a better way?

Comment: The type url may contain multiple `.` characters, so you need to split at the right place.